# Fields are added dynamically to the form but not submitted to the server

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to be able to add different fields to the form on the fly and then submit them to the server. This is how I do that:

```
var frm = this.up('window').down('form');
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var el = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text',{
                 xtype:'textfield',
                 name:'field_' + i
             });
    frm.items(add);
}
alert(frm.getForm().getFields().length); // alerts "0";
```

It is really interesting, because I even see three new fields in the form - they have their unique ids, names, etc. But for some insane reason `frm.getForm().getFields().length` gives me zero, even if I defer this by 2, 5 or infinity seconds. What is going on???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
frm.add(el);
```

Instead of:

```
frm.items(add);
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be some protection on Server Side against that (in order to protect against [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting))

I have faced with same when worked with Drupal (Apache), but I'm sure it's generic practice for many frameworks/servers.

Comment: Actually, it is not the case, because even on the client `frm.getForm().getFields().length` equals to zero, no matter how long I defer it.

Comment: @Jacobian can you make an example on JSFiddle? Since you have same issue on client, it's most likely not depended on server but to client side.

Comment: Seems like, we've solved it! Thank you for trying to help!